# Polling on Backend without ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on a project that creates a gallery of templates on the frontend. This is using ajax polling. Every (n) seconds we call this url (http://image-generator.com/getImage?template=2342) if image is already available we get the image url else we wait for (n) seconds and repeat the process.

```
function getPreview(url, params) {
    $.ajax({
    url : 'http://image-generator.com/getImage',
    data : params, // {template_id : 1234}
    success : function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
        $('<img />').attr('src', data.src).appendTo('#somecontainer');
        } else {
      // on queue
      setTimeout(function() {
                getPreview(data.url, data.params);
            }, 3000);
        } 
    }
    });  
}
```

This is what I have currently not a real code just for you to get the idea. but it's not really cool so I want to replace it. Instead of polling in frontend I want to do polling on backend.

I already made my research and found out the following:

> 1. Using sleep on backend
>
>    - Is this a good approach or it will eat up a lot of memory because I'll be calling a number of templates.
> 2. Using websocket
>
>    - is this cool?
> 3. Any other approach/suggestion you can think of?

**UPDATE** 
I've updated this url (http://image-generator.com/getImage) that instead of returning json I just redirect it to the actual image url.

Thanks,
MadJoe

Comment: You can't use sleep, as you need to send data from the server to the browser. Sleep on server won't do anything. There methods like long polling, Server Sent Events (SSE) and WebSocket can be used replacement.

Comment: What does *"it's not cool"* mean specifically?

Comment: @11thdimension, In long polling will it not be a problem if there's a lot of open connections since I'll be sending a lot of templates to the server for processing.

Comment: @charlietfl, it means not really a good solution because it cost a lot of request to the server.

Comment: The approaches you suggested in all of them you have to initiate the request from front end. So in every case you have to use Ajax to hit the server.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia ajax is not used for websockets

Comment: Then how the server will come to know that you are asking about new request

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, I've update this url(http://image-generator.com/getImage) that instead of echoing json I just redirect it to the actual image url. so no more ajax call.

Comment: @MadJoe, IMHO, what you are doing (with ajax) is actually quite ok already. I'd have done the same thing.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia suggest you read up on how websockets work if you are not sure

Comment: You can either drive this in the browser using code like what you have there, or you can drive it on the server using a WebSocket back-end. As a note, WebSockets and PHP are not the best mix, so you'd probably want a different endpoint for that, which means your AJAX solution is the easiest to get done.

Comment: take a look at http://oboejs.com/ - might help

Comment: Any method that you use for polling with no burden of reestablishing the connection would have to use a dedicated socket, SSE/Long Polling/Websocket. Checkout this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxakp15CACY , it covers the techs used for this sort of ues cases quite well.

Comment: @MadJoe, to add the reason for my previous comment, the polling is only temporary until the image preview is ready (few seconds top?) and combined with your polling interval (3 seconds), there might be only 1 or 2 polls per image, it's cool. If we are talking about real time chat, then maybe websokcet is better.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your suggestions I've come up with a solution that instead of using polling I'll just show a temporary thumbnail to the user when the image is not yet available. Thanks a lot. Love you guys.